# merging two or more columns in a pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3       col_4    col_5        col_6
  234.     61.     71.       age=23   sal=45k.  bonus_sal=61
  462.     371.    73.       age=64   sal=70k.  bonus_sal=66
```

And I want to combine col_4, col_5, col_6 so that my data frame become like:

```
col_1    col_2    col_3             col_4 
 234.     61.     71.       age=23;sal=45k;bonus_sal=61
 462.     371.    73.       age=64;sal=70k;bonus_sal=66
```

How can I achieve this using pandas? Also, this is just a example data frame. The real data frame has last twenty columns to be combined like that. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
df['merged_columns'] = df['col_4'].astype(str) + ";" + df['col_5'].astype(str) + ";" + df['col_6'].astype(str) + ";"
```

which will bring them together.

If you have many columns in your dataframe you want to `join`, with a specific characteristic, for example `col_` in their name (as your example above indicates), you can use list comprehension:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'col_' in col] 
df['columns_combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ';'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes I did that. But like I said I have twenty columns so I would have to write df['col'] twenty times. I was thinking if this could be done in a loop some how maybe?

Comment: Yes you can do it using a list comprehension - see the edited answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Since the real data frame includes many columns, you could try the following:

```
    y=3
    df[f'col_{y+1}'] = df[df.columns[y:]].apply(lambda x:";".join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
```

where y is the first column you want to merge with the following ones (index starts at 0).

Then, if you want you could drop the merged columns like that:

```
    df.drop(df.columns[y:-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `pop`

```
df['col_4'] = df.pop('col_4')+';'+df.pop('col_5')+';'+df.pop('col_6')

df
Out[390]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3                         col_4
0  234.0   61.0   71.0  age=23;sal=45k.;bonus_sal=61
1  462.0  371.0   73.0  age=64;sal=70k.;bonus_sal=66
```